# Magento2 paypal payflow pro $0.0 authorization charge issue

Tags: magento2, paypal, paypal-payflow-pro, authorize

I am facing an issue with Paypal payflow pro payment method in Magento2.2.5. Actually when i place order and check transaction in paypal manager account, it shows me 2 transaction entries, one for authorization and one for sales, i have checked in admin settings, Payment Action already set to Sale. please find attached screenshot for your reference

[image: paypal]

Can anyone help me out how to prevent authorization request to be sent to paypal and only send Sale request?